# How to use Split Screen to open 2 application at a time in Android/ Android TV Box

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am developing an Application from which on click of a button I wanted to open an another application or TV in exactly half of the screen. How can I split the Display for 2 separate applications.
Please help me in this case. 
I only wanted to show 2 applications at a time using any way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can look here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40638/how-do-i-run-two-programs-at-once-in-split-screen . Those guys give some hints on where to start, but not at programmatic level.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project.[Here](https://github.com/Udinic/ActivitySplitAnimation)

This is similar to what you want.You can't show two applications but you can show two screens of one app at same time.